# Razor code block usage

Tags: asp.net-webpages, webmatrix-2, razor-2

I'm just getting started with webpages and I can't quite figure out why a code block doesn't work. I need to conditionally display a WebGrid. Before I started I have this:

```
<div>
@grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Now I try to insert an if statement:

```
<div>
  @if (condition) { grid.GetHtml(); }
</div>
```

This results in no grid html displaying. In fact even without the if statement and just with a code block I get no html:

```
<div>
  @{ grid.GetHtml(); }
</div>
```

Unfortunately i'm running WebMatrix so I can't debug, but it seems whenever I use code blocks the statements don't execute.

Comment: OK it seems I need to use another @ symbol for the HTML output:    `@if (condition) {  @grid.GetHtml() }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one line statements you should use the @ sign instead of putting it in a code block. 
If you still put it in a code block (there are some cases you need to) it won't display your grid by just calling `grid.GetHtml();` This is why the @ sign is used, it means that you want to write out some value, but you should only use this if you are writing in HTML code. When using a code block, you have to tell the server that this value should be written out, like this:

```
@{
this.Write(grid.GetHtml());
}
```